# Outlook Web Add-in for Outlook Desktop CLient. ( Sent Button EVent)

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We are working on outlook web add-in. This add-in is supposed to trigger on Send button click event ( while sending email or meeting ).

So far we have seen that this add-in works fine in OWA(https://outlook.office.com/owa) but Outlook Client it is working for a specific version of outlook say Windows 10 Enterprise and Outlook client version 2006 (Build 13001.20384) but for other versions like outlook version 1908 (Build 11929.20904) the send button event is not triggering.

Also, dose send event have any windows OS build version dependency?

e.g
TESTINGVMTWO (**Add-in Not Working** - Send Button even is not triggering)
Host Name:                 testvmtwo
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763? Not working for this build
Outlook Version:          Version 2006 (Build 13001.20384)

TESTING_VM: (**Add-in Working** send button event triggers and add-in works as expected)
Host Name:                 Testing-VM
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041
Outlook Version: Version 2007 (Build 13029.20308)

Your help or advice is much appreciated.

Regards

Shrirang

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see this article: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/

Depending on both Office Version and Windows Version, either Edge or IE will be used to render / run your add-in.

This is just a guess, but it is likely there is some code in your add-in that is incompatible with IE. (maybe Arrow Functions?)